# Using `waiter` package lead to JS error in Shiny with a `DT` object

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

In the below Shiny example, if one want to switch the number of rows displayed in the DT object, from 8 initially to for instance 25 or 50 (10 is okay), the table display remain unchanged.

One will observe when "inspecting" the webpage that this switch lead to a console error (which appears to comes from waiter.js):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.document.onscroll (waiter.js:241)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js:2)
    at na (<anonymous>:74:135)
    at aa (<anonymous>:26:423)
    at v.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:140:512)
    at v.iterator (<anonymous>:113:209)
```

Disabling package `waiter` fix the problem.

Anyone knows how to fix this? Why does waiter try to catch what I understand to be related to the height of the DT object?

Below the MRE:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(waiter)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(waiter::use_waiter(),
                waiter::use_steward(),
                waiter::waiter_show_on_load(),
                DT::DTOutput("rt"))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  Sys.sleep(2)
  output$rt <- DT::renderDT({
    DT::datatable(mtcars,
                  selection = 'single',
                  options = list(
                    scrollX = TRUE,
                    pageLength = 8,
                    dom = 'ltp')) %>% 
      DT::formatStyle(columns = colnames(mtcars), fontSize = '90%')
  })
  waiter::waiter_hide()
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I am indeed using 0.7.5, I updated the code with a line to install this version rather than the 2.0. Otherwise the problem may still occur with a classic shiny dashboard.

Comment: By the way this is not induced by this package, I updated the inital MRE with standard `shinydashboard` package.

Comment: https://github.com/JohnCoene/waiter/issues/98

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug already fixed in the dev version of the tool. Source : https://github.com/JohnCoene/waiter/issues/98
Requires R >= 4.1.0